# Rewards for completing landmarks and hints?

Tags: prototype

Is there any advantage or achievement after completing the landmarks/hints across the world?

Is it worth completing them? I feel Prototype is somehow an open-world game and it'll really take time gathering them.

Answer (score 1):

You gain Evolution Point (XP) for every 10 landmark and every 10 hints. The EP given grow too, and there is a Trophies for completing them.

Beyond that, I have ~75% of landmark and ~60% of hints and didn t got anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You gain EP for each landmark and hint collectible you find. The EP value of each collectible increases as you find more of them. There are also achievements/trophies associated with finding all of them (sadly, the Steam version does not have achievements). There are no other bonuses to finding the collectibles.